# What exactly is a modulus of continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

This is my first post on here, so forgive me if I am ignorant of certain customs.

I am currently reading Courant & John's *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis Volume I*. Unfortunately, I have stumbled upon an ambiguous notation on page 41.

It begins:

> Our definition of continuity of the function $f(x)$ at $x_0$ requires that for every degree of precision $\epsilon > 0$ there exists quantities $\delta \gt 0$ (so-called moduli of continuity) such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ for which $|x-x_0| < \delta$.

He then goes on to say that (for "regular continuity"):

> In general, as our example show, this $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ depends not only on $\epsilon$ but also on the value of $x_0$.

What exactly is meant by a modulus of continuity and how is it related to $\delta(\epsilon)$?

Edit - Upon further inspection I have noted that the "modulus of continuity" depends on both $x_0$  and $\epsilon$ for "regular continuity", however only depends on $\epsilon$ for uniform continuity. I believe that some of the confusion has been cleared by the notation of $\delta(\epsilon)$. However, he states that moduli of continuity are simply quantities $\delta > 0$. Is this "it", or is there further discussion to be had?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was also uncertain as to whether this was a definition, however the Wikipedia article seems to be much clearer. Likewise, using $\omega$ seems more useful as $\delta(\epsilon)$ led to my confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of continuity of a function $f$ at $x_0$ is: For any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon $ provided that $|x-x_0|<\delta $.

We thus say that for every $\varepsilon $ there is a corresponding $\delta $, in the sense that the above statement holds. The thing to notice is that

1) The precise value of $\delta$ may depend on both $\varepsilon $ and the point $x_0$.

2) For any given $\varepsilon >0 $ and $x_0$, there may be many choices for $\delta$ as above.

Any choice of $\delta$ for a given $\varepsilon $ and $x_0$ is called a modulus of continuity for $f$ at $x_0$ corresponding to $\varepsilon $. Moduli of continuity are not unique.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the elaboration. The confusion stemmed from the use of $\delta(\epsilon)$ to indicate a dependence upon $\epsilon$ and $x_0$. So the author is using this notation to indicate a modulus of continuity?

Comment: Ittay Weiss explained very well what Courant means, but the notion of *modulus of continuity* is frequently used in other, nearly *inverse* sense. It is a function that permits to estimate the difference of the values of a function for a given $\delta$. See [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) and [link](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Continuity,_modulus_of).

Comment: @EgorMaximenko in which sense do you see the notion of modulus of continuity in the links you provide to be any different (let alone inverse) to what is described above?

Comment: @Ittay Weiss: In Courant, $\delta$ is a function of $\varepsilon$ and $x_0$. In EncyclopediaOfMath, the uniform modulus of continuity $\omega$ is a function of $\delta$ defined as the sup of $|f(x)-f(y)|$ over all pairs $x,y$ satisfying $|x-y|\le\delta$. For example, if $f(x)=x/5$, then $\delta(\varepsilon)$ can be $5\varepsilon$, and $\omega(\delta)=\delta/5$. In this simple example the inverse of $\omega$ can be used as Courant's $\delta$.

Comment: I disagree that the notions are inverse to each other. If $w$ is a modulus of continuity, and $\varepsilon >0$ is given, then there is some $\delta >0 $ with $w(\delta) < \varepsilon$. This $\delta $ is then a corresponding modulus of continuity in the above sense. I don't see any significant difference between the notions.

Comment: Courant considers $\delta$ as a function of $\varepsilon$, and $\omega$ calculates $\varepsilon$ for each $\delta$ (roughly speaking). In the case if $\omega$ is continuous and strictly increasing, then its *inverse* can be used as a $\delta$. For example, if $f$ is defined on $[0,+\infty)$ by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, then $\omega(\delta)=\sqrt{\delta}$. If $x_0=0$ and $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, then we can't put $\delta=\omega(\varepsilon)$, but we can put $\delta=\epsilon^2=\omega^{-1}(\varepsilon)$. I agree that both functions, $\omega$ and $\omega^{-1}$, relate $\delta$ with $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @EgorMaximenko I think I might have misinterpreted your saying that the two notions are inverse to each other to mean they express different things. I think we agree they essentially carry the same (or almost the same) information, but in somewhat different ways.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss: You are right, my phrase that the *notions have nearly inverse sense* is wrong. The two functions carry almost the same information, like $\sin$ and $\arcsin$.

Comment: Okay so Modulus of continuity for a function f, can be thought of as a function $ m:\mathbb R^{+}\times \mathbb R^{+}\to \mathbb R^{+}$, as $m_f(x_0,\epsilon)$